# Abount ConvertFrom-Json and pipeline Foreach

Tags: powershell, powershell-6.0

Why the following two behave differently?

```
'[{"b":1}]'|ConvertFrom-Json|%{$_}|gm
```

```
'[{"b":1}]'|ConvertFrom-Json|gm
```

they seems like different types. My PS version is 6.2.3

Comment: Looks like the first example is forced enumeration of the output. The second example does no enumeration. It’s possibly a bug given that the `-noenumerate` switch (default value of false) was added to later versions of the command. With the second example, if you pipe back to `convertto-json`, your json data will be correct.

Comment: @AdminOfThings yeah I found it. Thank you